# Was Eratosthenes justified in his belief the earth was round?

Tags: visible-light, earth, history, geometry, sun

Because I see two flaws with it, firstly he assumes the distance of the sun won't affect the angle at which light hits the pole. If the sun were far closer and far smaller, there would be a change in the angle at which the light hits the pole, affecting the results.

Secondly, just because he finds an 800km portion of the earth is curved it does not follow the rest of the earth is curved the same way creating a sphere.

Comment: The first statement is incorrect, assuming the sun is small enough to be considered a point source, wish is not far from real as the sun's size on the sky is small, then the angle is independent of distance.  Your second complain is valid, it assumes that earth is round.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the [hsm.se]

Comment: Whether someone was justified in their belief is a matter of opinion, surely ?

Answer (score 3):

Eratosthenes thought of an interesting hypothesis, that the world is round like an orange not flat like a plate. He also realised that if the world was round like an orange then certain facts about the sun and the local vertical would follow, and furthermore a measurement would enable an estimate of the radius of the world to be made. I don't know exactly what Eratosthenes thought, but I imagine his idea was not only based on shadows, sunlight and wells and the like, but also on a sense of coherence about the idea as a whole, the way it means there needn't be an edge. I think he surely also knew that ships appear to sink below the horizon as they go into the distance. So overall he had several lines of evidence, and a coherent basic idea. I would say that yes, this is enough to justify holding the opinion that the shape of the world is more like an orange than a plate. Holding this opinion would not require, for Eratosthenes, that he consider himself certain of it, only that he might hold that it is a reasonable conclusion at which to arrive, and that in view of this further tests and explorations would be worthwhile.

Comment: That's the same as how science works today; Dream up a theory, consider its implications and derive hypotheses from it, perform experiments to test the hypotheses, share the results. Positive results strengthen belief that the theory _might_ be true. Negative result? Maybe you can modify the theory. If not, better luck next time.